# does eclipse allow watching only one expression at a time

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am trying to watch expressions, but I am able to watch only one expression at a time.

Say I have three expressions below

- Integer.toString(i)
- Integer.toString(i*2)
- Integer.toString(i*3)

But at a time, I can see the value of only one of these expressions, the one that I choose to click on.

I was hoping to see the values of all the expressions side-by-side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the values of all the expressions are only be seen one by one

[image]

Firstly, the expression is actually input by ourself, when input an expression, the result is shown on the right

Secondly,we can modify the expression value, such as, print the `i` value, then, we will increase `i` value by expression `i = 2`, lastly, print the `i` value again.if these expression are executed side by side, I guess the result has many 
possibility.

Comment: but I'm not able to see the values of each expression like you. I only see value of any one expression at a time.

Comment: I use the window system. the version of eclipse is eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32